# How to turn on activity-based application into a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, converters, super

I learn programming mobile applications. I decided to convert one application of Activity is a fragment, but I have a problem. Maybe some of you will be able to help me.

```
package pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.fragment;

    import android.app.Fragment;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.text.TextWatcher;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TabHost;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import org.androidannotations.annotations.EFragment;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.R;
    import pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.todoList.DatabaseHandler;
    import pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.todoList.Task;

    @EFragment(R.layout.fragment_todo)
    public class TODOFragment extends Fragment {

        EditText zadanieTxt, opisTxt, dataTxt, adresTxt;
        List<Task> Tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
        ListView TaskListView;
        DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_todo, container, false);
        }
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();


            zadanieTxt = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtZadanie);
            opisTxt = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtOpis);
            dataTxt = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtData);
            adresTxt = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtAdres);
            TaskListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);
            dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

            TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) getView().findViewById(R.id.baner);

            tabHost.setup();

            TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Dodaj zadanie");
            tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabZadanie);
            tabSpec.setIndicator("Dodaj Zadanie");
            tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

            tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("lista");
            tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabListaZadan);
            tabSpec.setIndicator("Lista");
            tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

            final Button addBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
            addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Task task = new Task(dbHandler.getTaskCount(), String.valueOf(zadanieTxt.getText()), String.valueOf(opisTxt.getText()), String.valueOf(dataTxt.getText()), String.valueOf(adresTxt.getText()));
                    if (!taskExists(task)) {
                        dbHandler.createZadanie(task);
                        Tasks.add(task);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(zadanieTxt.getText()) + " zostało dodane do listy zadań!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(zadanieTxt.getText()) + " Zadanie już istnieje", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            zadanieTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                    addBtn.setEnabled(String.valueOf(zadanieTxt.getText()).trim().length() > 0);
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });



            if (dbHandler.getTaskCount() != 0)
                Tasks.addAll(dbHandler.getAllTasks());

            populateList();
        }

        private boolean taskExists(Task task) {
            String zadanie = task.getZadanie();
            int taskCount = Tasks.size();

            for (int i = 0; i < taskCount; i++) {
                if (zadanie.compareToIgnoreCase(Tasks.get(i).getZadanie()) == 0)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    //    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {
    //        if (resCode == RESULT_OK) {
    //            if (reqCode == 1) {
    //                imageUri = data.getData();
    //                contactImageImgView.setImageURI(data.getData());
    //            }
    //        }
    //    }

        private void populateList() {
            ArrayAdapter<Task> adapter = new TaskListAdapter();
            TaskListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        private class TaskListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {
            public TaskListAdapter()
            {

                super (TODOFragment.this, R.layout.listview_item, Tasks);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
                if (view == null)
                    view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

                Task currentTask = Tasks.get(position);

                TextView zadanie = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.zadanie);
                zadanie.setText(currentTask.getZadanie());
                TextView opis = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.opis);
                opis.setText(currentTask.getOpis());
                TextView data = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.data);
                data.setText(currentTask.getData());
                TextView adres = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adres);
                adres.setText(currentTask.getAdres());

                return view;
            }
        }



    }
```

The problem is here:

```
private class TaskListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {
        public TaskListAdapter()
        {

            super (TODOFragment.this, R.layout.listview_item, Tasks);
        }
```

What can I do ?

There is a Message Gradle Build

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72000Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42000Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk3211Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComMakeramenRoundedimageview150Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:compileDebugJava
Note: Resolve log file to C:\Users\Kisiel\AndroidStudioProjects\Studentizer\app\build\generated\source\apt\androidannotations.log
Note: Initialize AndroidAnnotations 3.2 with options {androidManifestFile=C:\Users\Kisiel\AndroidStudioProjects\Studentizer\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml}
Note: Start processing for 17 annotations on 32 elements
Note: AndroidManifest.xml file found with specified path: C:\Users\Kisiel\AndroidStudioProjects\Studentizer\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
Note: AndroidManifest.xml found: AndroidManifest [applicationPackage=pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp, componentQualifiedNames=[pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.DrawerActivity_, pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.FragmentActivity_], permissionQualifiedNames=[android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.CAMERA, android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.SEND_SMS], applicationClassName=null, libraryProject=false, debugabble=false, minSdkVersion=9, maxSdkVersion=-1, targetSdkVersion=20]
Note: Found project R class: pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.R
Note: Found Android class: android.R
Note: Validating elements
Note: Validating with EActivityHandler: [pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.DrawerActivity, pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.FragmentActivity]
Note: Validating with EFragmentHandler: [pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.fragment.DashboardFragment, pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.fragment.TimetableFragment, pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.fragment.TODOFragment, pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.fragment.WalletFragment]
Note: Validating with EBeanHandler: [pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.navigationDrawer.DrawerHandler, pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.navigationDrawer.DrawerListAdapter, pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.skmTimetable.adapter.TrainsListAdapter, pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.skmTimetable.backgroundTasks.RestBackgroundTrainLeft, pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.skmTimetable.backgroundTasks.RestBackgroundTrainRight]
Note: Validating with EViewGroupHandler: [pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.navigationDrawer.DrawerItemView, pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.skmTimetable.itemView.TrainItemView]
Note: Validating with ViewByIdHandler: [stanMiasto, stanPogoda, stanC, listTrainLeftLstView, listTrainRightLstView, refreshBtn, restoreGpsBtn, startIdSpinner, endIdSpinner, text, leftTxtView, rightTxtView, leftLayout, rightLayout, drawerLayout, drawerList, icon, name, hour, minute, tip]
Note: Validating with ClickHandler: [refreshBtnClicked(), restoreGpsBtn()]
Note: Validating with RestHandler: [pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.dashboard.DashboardRestClient, pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.skmTimetable.SkmRestClient]
Note: Validating with GetHandler: [getTrains(int,int,int), getTrains(int,int,int)]
Note: Validating with OptionsItemHandler: [drawerToggleSelected(android.view.MenuItem)]
Note: Validating with RestServiceHandler: [restClient, restClient]
Note: Validating with RootContextHanlder: [drawerActivity, context, context, activity, activity]
Note: Validating with NonConfigurationInstanceHandler: [restBackgroundTrainLeft, restBackgroundTrainRight]
Note: Validating with BeanHandler: [restBackgroundTrainLeft, restBackgroundTrainRight, drawerHandler, adapterLeft, adapterRight, drawerListAdapter]
Note: Validating with AfterInjectHandler: [init()]
Note: Validating with AfterViewsHandler: [init(), init(), init(), init()]
Note: Validating with UiThreadHandler: [publishResult(pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.skmTimetable.data.TrainsList), publishError(java.lang.Exception), publishWarning(), publishResult(pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.skmTimetable.data.TrainsList), publishError(java.lang.Exception), publishWarning()]
Note: Validating with BackgroundHandler: [getTrains(int,int,int), getTrains(int,int,int)]
Note: Processing root elements
Note: Processing root elements EActivityHandler: [pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.FragmentActivity, pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.DrawerActivity]
Note: Processing root elements EFragmentHandler: [pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.fragment.WalletFragment, pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.fragment.TimetableFragment, pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.fragment.DashboardFragment, pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.fragment.TODOFragment]
Note: Processing root elements EBeanHandler: [pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.skmTimetable.backgroundTasks.RestBackgroundTrainLeft, pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.skmTimetable.backgroundTasks.RestBackgroundTrainRight, pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.navigationDrawer.DrawerListAdapter, pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.skmTimetable.adapter.TrainsListAdapter, pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.navigationDrawer.DrawerHandler]
Note: Processing root elements EViewGroupHandler: [pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.navigationDrawer.DrawerItemView, pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.skmTimetable.itemView.TrainItemView]
Note: Processing root elements RestHandler: [pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.skmTimetable.SkmRestClient, pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.dashboard.DashboardRestClient]
Note: Processing enclosed elements
Note: Number of files generated by AndroidAnnotations: 15
Note: Writting following API classes in project: []
Note: Generating class: pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.skmTimetable.itemView.TrainItemView_
Note: Generating class: pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.fragment.DashboardFragment_
Note: Generating class: pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.fragment.TODOFragment_
Note: Generating class: pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.fragment.TimetableFragment_
Note: Generating class: pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.fragment.WalletFragment_
Note: Generating class: pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.skmTimetable.adapter.TrainsListAdapter_
Note: Generating class: pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.skmTimetable.SkmRestClient_
Note: Generating class: pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.dashboard.DashboardRestClient_
Note: Generating class: pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.DrawerActivity_
Note: Generating class: pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.FragmentActivity_
Note: Generating class: pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.skmTimetable.backgroundTasks.RestBackgroundTrainLeft_
Note: Generating class: pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.skmTimetable.backgroundTasks.RestBackgroundTrainRight_
Note: Generating class: pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.navigationDrawer.DrawerHandler_
Note: Generating class: pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.navigationDrawer.DrawerItemView_
Note: Generating class: pl.edu.ug.aib.studentizerApp.navigationDrawer.DrawerListAdapter_
Note: Time measurements: [Whole Processing = 187 ms], [Generate Sources = 100 ms], [Process Annotations = 38 ms], [Validate Annotations = 17 ms], [Find R Classes = 10 ms], [Extract Annotations = 9 ms], [Extract Manifest = 6 ms], 
Note: Finish processing
Note: Start processing for 0 annotations on 15 elements
Note: Time measurements: [Whole Processing = 0 ms], 
Note: Finish processing
Note: Start processing for 0 annotations on 0 elements
Note: Time measurements: [Whole Processing = 1 ms], 
Note: Finish processing
C:\Users\Kisiel\AndroidStudioProjects\Studentizer\app\src\main\java\pl\edu\ug\aib\studentizerApp\navigationDrawer\DrawerListAdapter.java
Error:(36, 19) error: constructor DrawerItem in class DrawerItem cannot be applied to given types;
required: int,int,Class<? extends Fragment>
found: String,int,Class<TODOFragment_>
reason: actual argument String cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion
Note: C:\Users\Kisiel\AndroidStudioProjects\Studentizer\app\src\main\java\pl\edu\ug\aib\studentizerApp\fragment\TimetableFragment.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 5.649 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Try to clearify what you need to resolve, also, show us if there are any error codes when running the code. You can edit your question to expand it.

Answer (score 0):

the `super (TODOFragment.this, R.layout.listview_item, Tasks);` 
is looking for a context where you have TODOFragment.this (which is a Fragment and thus not a Context).

Try calling TODOFragment.this.getActivity() instead of TODOFragment.this and you should be all set.